# How to understand the symbolic method name in JVM?

Tags: java, methods, jvm, method-names

I tried to dump the methods' symbolic names. e.g.

```
<SystemAppCL,Ldacapo/parser/Config$OutputFile;>.hasLines()Z
```

The strange thing is that I also got some similar names. e.g.

```
<SystemAppCL,Ldacapo/parser/Config$OutputFile;,<init>,(Ldacapo/parser/Config;Ljava/lang/String;)V>
<SystemAppCL,Ldacapo/parser/Config$OutputFile;>.<init>(Ldacapo/parser/Config;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Are these two represent the same method? Are they both legal? Why they are different?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you dump these names?  Can you provide the source code for these classes (or create a small example for which you can)?